# Javascript : How to put a string into new line if enter key is detected

Tags: javascript, string, newline

I have a string like this.

**ABC↵XYZ↵PQR**

I want every string in new line after ↵

Something like this

ABC

XYZ

PQR

```js
let str = 'ABC↵XYZ↵PQR'

let newString =str.replace(/\n/ig, '');

console.log("New String : " , newString)
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Where do you want to output it?

Comment: I would like to have it in HTML div.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place it in HTML try adding HTML line breaks:

```js
const str = 'ABC↵XYZ↵PQR'

const newString = str.replace(/↵/ig, '<br>');

console.log("New String : ", newString);

const place = document.getElementById('place');

place.innerHTML = newString;
```

```html
<div id="place"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this enough?

```
'ABC↵XYZ↵PQR'.replace(/↵/ig, '\n');
```

In your example you're just removing any \n (replacing with '') that's why it can't work.

```js
let str = 'ABC↵XYZ↵PQR'

let newString =str.replace(/↵/ig, '\n');

console.log("New String : " , newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.replaceAll` method match for solving this problem.

```js
let str = 'ABC↵XYZ↵PQR'

let newString =str.replaceAll('↵', '\n');

console.log("New String : ");
console.log(newString);
```